# Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $( document ).on( 'pjax:complete', () => { ... } );} );

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have legacy code like this below. My goal replace **jQuery** in the project to pure **JS**.

```
...
$( document ).on( 'pjax:complete', () => {
    executeSomething();
} );
...
```

`executeSomething()` - accesses to API, executes some calculations based on it and renders the result on the active tab.

I wrapped this function to [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and it works

```
...
( function() {
    executeSomething();
})();
...
```

**Question**: Is this a similar implementation?

Dependencies

- jQuery v3.2.0

Comment: _"Is this a similar implementation?"_ <- not even close

Comment: @Phil Where can i read about this? I find links only to libraries and frameworks.

Comment: `pjax:complete` appears to be an event triggered by the [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) library. This **will not work** without jQuery

Answer (score 2):

```
document.addEventListener('pjax:complete', () => {
  executeSomething();
});
```

An IIFE executes immediately. An event listener triggers the function only when the event occurs.

Comment: Thank you but what does it means `pjax:complete`? Where can i read about this? I find links only to libraries and frameworks. The code stopped working with your implementation

Comment: The problem is that `pjax:complete` is something from a jQuery plugin - you can't remove jQuery from the page and have `pjax` keep working, whatever it does (not in your question). But the general method to turn a jQuery event handler into a Javascript handler is still the way I said in the answer.